# How to set the default value property for an object represented in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

Say i have an object like

```
class Item
{
  string Value {get;set;}
}
class MyClass
{
    List<Item> Values {get;set;}
}
```

How can i make it so that when i'm using this object in XAML, i can set the value property like so.

```
<MyClass>
<Item>A</Item>
<Item>B</Item>
</MyClass>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, i needed to put a [ContentPropertyAttribute] on!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<MyClass>
    <MyClass.Values>
        <Item>A</Item>
        <Item>B</Item>
        <Item>C</Item>
    </MyClass.Values>
</MyClass>
```